# Exploration graphics in h2o

Tags: h2o

To whom may it concern,

Is it possible to plot an exploratory variable versus the target in h2o? I want to know whether it is possible to carry out basic data exploration in h2o, or whether it is not designed for that.

Many thanks in advance,
Kere

Answer (score 1):

the main plotting functionality for an H2O frame is for histograms (`hist()` in python and `h2o.hist()` in R).

Within Flow you can do basic data exploration if you import your dataframe, then click on `inspect` and then, next to the hyperlinked `columns`, you'll see a `plot` button which will let you get bar charts of counts for example and other plot types.

You can also easily convert single columns you want to plot into a pandas or R dataframe with
`H2OFrame.as_data_frame()` in python
`as.data.frame.H2OFrame` in R and then use the native python and R plotting methods